# Equivalence of closure of a sequence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let be $(X, || \cdot ||)$ a normed space and $A:=\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ a sequence, then:
\begin{equation*}
cl \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = A \cup P
\end{equation*}
Where cl denotes the closure and $P = \{ x \in X: \hspace{.1cm} (B_\epsilon(x)\setminus \{ x \})\cap A \neq \varnothing \hspace{.1cm} \forall \epsilon >0 \}$ i. e. the accumulation points set. I have tried to do the proof but  can not achieve it, the contention $A \cup P \subset cl \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is immediate.

Comment: There are several ways of defining the closure of a set. The union of the set and its accumulation points is a common one. Obviously it is not the definition you are using, so what is the definition you are using?

Comment: $P=A'$, the set of limit points of $A$, so this is true if you define (as many texts seem to do) $\operatorname{cl}(A)= A \cup A'$ by definition...